# Difference between -- and 0 in Azure Service Bus message count

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

What's the difference between these two?

I used to see `--` all the time and assumed it meant 0, but now I can actually see "0".

[image]

Comment: AFAIK that are null values, meaning there haven't been any values registered so far but I can't back it up with official docs.